# How we can add google map that interact with google data studio & data studio filter

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I want to connect the google maps with my google data studio report in an interactive manner. Using data I need to show the routes on google map also I need to update the routes when I apply the filter on report.

Embedding a Google Map is not helping because it's static.

Is there any way to do it interactively ? should I use community visualisations for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: Take a look at [Maps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps)

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Maps](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713352) chart type was introduced into Google Data Studio in the [May 1st 2020 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/43790855), and allows for interactions with [Filter Controls](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) as well as the other components available in Google Data Studio.

Adding an [Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/60010558-8351-40c6-8ba5-af9d432235b0) as well as a GIF (from an [Earlier Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041050/12892553)) to elaborate:

[image]