# How can I make a Geo Chart display one specific country and its regions in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio, geomap

A [Geo Chart](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7065037) usually shows entire world.

How to show one country's region and color them according to my data?

Also how can I group my data in a table so Data Studio can actually represent regions of my country?

e.g. I have 3 countries and number of accounts in each country, in what column can I put regional data for my country?

| country | account_number | region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| russia | 324 | ?? |
| kazakhstan | 5785 | ?? |
| america | 2342 | ?? |

I have added a report, Data Studio recognizes the country by country code, but from there it's not clear how to highlight regions by numbers:

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/995d854e-daff-47f6-8b91-6f816a255810)

Answer (score 1):

One way it can be achieved is by using:

- ***Chart Type***: [Google Maps](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713352)
- ***Bubble Location***: `region`
- ***Bubble Colour***: `country`
- **Metric**: `metric`

Created an [Editable Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YeRHMayLroEOd20sAtrH-8plALJwhPbNsTQjA1VJ5ok/edit?usp=sharing) with the sample data below with some random values for the `metric` field as well as adding a few values for the `region` field:

| country | account_number | region | metric |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Russia | 324 | Moscow | 54 |
| Russia | 325 | Saint Petersburg | 36 |
| Russia | 326 | Krasnodar Krai | 14 |
| Kazakhstan | 5785 | Almaty | 31 |
| Kazakhstan | 5786 | Astana | 57 |
| Kazakhstan | 5787 | Kyzylorda | 58 |
| United States | 2342 | New York | 28 |
| United States | 2343 | California | 99 |
| United States | 2344 | Texas | 30 |

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/60010558-8351-40c6-8ba5-af9d432235b0) as well as a GIF to elaborate:

[image]